# YouTube embed player not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Since a couple of days, code which worked fine to embed a YouTube video via Javascript stopped working. Now the video loads but it is not playable (the play button is not clickable), with this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.g.mX is not a function
at O_ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vfl8LqiZp/base.js:3796:24)
at new P_ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vfl8LqiZp/base.js:3791:111)
at new c2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vfl8LqiZp/base.js:3985:268)
at new i2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vfl8LqiZp/base.js:4005:210)
at i2.create (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vfl8LqiZp/base.js:6950:321)
at zh.<anonymous> (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflxTxlSH/www-embed-player.js:428:269)
at zh.k.lb (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflxTxlSH/www-embed-player.js:428:308)
at Dh (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflxTxlSH/www-embed-player.js:426:143)
at zh.k.pa (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflxTxlSH/www-embed-player.js:419:176)
at https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflxTxlSH/www-embed-player.js:461:420
```

The JS code is as follows:

```
document.getElementById('player').setAttribute("style","height:"+(window.innerHeight * 0.87)+"px;");
document.getElementById('youtube_frame').src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              height: "100%",
              width: "100%",
              videoId: start_video,
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
            });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {

            player_ref = event.target;
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // when video ends
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
            if(event.data === 0) {          

                event.target.loadVideoById(start_video);
            }
        }
```

Playback also broke on another prototype that I run. Everything used to work fine until a couple of days ago. I cannot find anything online, perhaps someone can shed some light?

----- **UPDATE** ----

Embedding playback is broken again:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.g.setActionHandler is not a function
at M_ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:3788:24)
at new N_ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:3783:111)
at new a2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:3978:367)
at new g2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:3999:210)
at g2.create (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:6995:333)
at Gi.<anonymous> (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:507:269)
at Gi.l.jb (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:507:308)
at Ki (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:505:143)
at Gi.l.oa (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:498:176)
at https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:557:378
```

Comment: Seeing the same error message, but via the Google IMA HTML5 SDK.

Comment: @almcd, could it be related to CORS or HTTPS ? Because on youtube.com there is the same error but the video plays fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @andrea-f . However, I’m no longer seeing the error message. Looks likely that Google’s fix has resolved the issue for the IMA SDK too.

Comment: @almcd yup, resolved

Comment: @almcd playback is broken again.

Comment: Not seeing it via the Google IMA HTML5 SDK. Either it doesn't affect the IMA SDK this time, or perhaps it has already been fixed.

Comment: @almcd yup already fixed, working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this problem in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) **when "experimental functions" are enabled.**

```
base.js:7046 Uncaught TypeError: a.g.setActionHandler is not a function
at bY (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-ru_RU-vfleBND20/base.js:3618:24)
at new cY (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-ru_RU-vfleBND20/base.js:3613:111)
at new z1 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-ru_RU-vfleBND20/base.js:3983:268)
at new j2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-ru_RU-vfleBND20/base.js:4044:209)
at Object.j2.create (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-ru_RU-vfleBND20/base.js:7045:317)
at Object.ytplayer.load (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-AdoTkXwbc:241:75024)
at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-AdoTkXwbc:241:75172
at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-AdoTkXwbc:241:75181
```

We can disable this option here: chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

**-- UPDATE 10.03.2017 --**

Chrome 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit) is published today and **works fine**!

Answer (score 7):

The issue has been resolved by Google and now YouTube videos play ok!

Wonder what happened?

----- **UPDATE 23/02/2017** ------

Embedding playback is broken again:

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.g.setActionHandler is not a function
at M_ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:3788:24)
at new N_ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:3783:111)
at new a2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:3978:367)
at new g2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:3999:210)
at g2.create (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflqOi6vK/base.js:6995:333)
at Gi.<anonymous> (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:507:269)
at Gi.l.jb (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:507:308)
at Ki (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:505:143)
at Gi.l.oa (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:498:176)
at https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:557:378
```

Comment: Still some error is coming for me, can you please help. It is happening for only IE9. ![imageUrl](http://i64.tinypic.com/2r583lh.png)

Comment: Seeing this for Chrome for the first time today. Anyone else?

Comment: Hi @Simon_Weaver yes me too.

Comment: It has just started happening in my up-to-date chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit). But works fine in colleagues, chrome. Also works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Even I am facing this issue in Chrome 56.0.2924.87(64-bit) while the same video is working fine in Canary 59.0.3033.0.

Comment: Join me to those experience this issue as well with up-to-date Chrome: Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: I`ve this problem when "experemental functions" enabled. We can disable this option here: chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the current problem is it is related to the `MediaSession` object while trying to attach an event (`play` in this case). This object is internal to Chrome so it seems something is corrupt there.

I'm seeing the same problem on any other website that uses YouTube - so don't waste your time trying to debug your own site. That's not the problem.

I've rebooted and tried to disable all extensions. Not seeing any fixes yet.

Mainly wanted to post this so people don't waste time thinking their code is bad.

[image]

Comment: Ya it suggests a corrupt chrome. But the issue isn't widespread which strikes me as weird. You can install chrome canary if you haven't already. I'm wondering if there was a recent update that broke it but I'm not able to check right now. Been seeing problems for about 4-5 days now

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Take a look at MixerOID's comment in the answer above. This appears to only affect Chrome when 'Experimental Web Platform features' are enabled.

Comment: @almcd thanks! That's very helpful. I forget why I enabled this option but pretty sure I had done so.

Comment: this morning everything seems fine again and all working, no update to Chrome though.